# Cohen-Macaulayness of rings of polynomials vanishing at points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, let $L_1$, $L_2$, ..., $L_r$ be subspaces and let $w_1$, $w_2$, ..., $w_r$ be positive rational numbers. Define a graded ring $R$ where $R_d$ is those degree $d$ polynomials $f$ such that $f$ vanishes to order $\geq w_i d$ on $L_i$, for $1 \leq i \leq r$. My understanding is that such rings can, in general, by very bad, maybe even not finitely generated.

My main question is about when these rings are good:

> Are there known combinatorial conditions on the $L_i$ and $w_i$ such that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

Side questions:

> When $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, is there a nice description of the dualizing module?

> Do things get any simpler if I pass to a Veronese subring (meaning $\bigoplus_k R_{ak}$ for some $a$) sufficient to clear all the denominators of the $w_i$?

For example, one ring that I would like to think about is to take the $L_i$ to be $6$ generic lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^3$ and $w_1 = w_2 = \cdots = w_6 = 1/6$. I'd be perfectly glad to just understand the subring in degrees divisible by $6$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but isn't in the example the $k$-th component of the ring is just the space of global sections of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(k(6\ell - e_1 - \dots - e_6))$ on the blowup of the projective plane in the six point corresponding to the $L_i$, and so the ring is just the coordinate ring of this blowup in the embedding given by the ample divisor class $6\ell - e_1 - \dots - e_6$?

Comment: Yes, this is right. It is a bit more confusing when the spaces are nested and you get nested blows ups, but yes, these should all be rings of sections on repeated blowups of projective space.

Comment: So, in this particular example, do you want to just understand generators and relations? Or something different?

Comment: I want to know what conditions to put on $w_i$ and $L_i$ to force Cohen-Macaulayness of the section ring.